# Some application to obtain a beep (shell) command since a midi file

Tags: shell, midi, beep

Someone knows an application to obtain a beep command (for shell), from a midi file? It's to play the midi with the shell.
Thanks.

Comment: Which operating system? And what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The OS is debian 9.

Comment: The problem is, that i have a midi file, and i want to generate a shell script, to play the song in the midi file, with the beep command.